# How do I install a demo schema like SCOTT / TIGER on Oracle Database 21c XE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle21c

How can I install a demo schema like SCOTT / TIGER on Oracle Database 21c XE if there are no files in my [ORACLE_HOME]/sqlplus/demo directory?

Comment: For the old `SCOTT` schema, see Littlefoot's answer. For the sample schemas that Oracle is using in its last few versions, see the Oracle documentation, for example: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SCOTT` schema is available from [Oracle's Github account](https://github.com/oracle) (rather than third parties) in the ["dotnet-db-samples" repository](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/blob/master/schemas/scott.sql).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'm allowed to post the script itself (as I don't own the copyright), but - follow [this link](https://gist.github.com/julianhyde/31f338365ebd0d3109d98121d859c86b), copy code you find there and run it in `SCOTT` schema you previously created in your database.